# Vaadin Flow: set Password Reveal Button Attributes

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am trying to replace the Aria Label of the Password Field reveal button with a different text.

[As you can see in developer tools the button is inside the Password Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyS1G.png)

My approach would have been to execute JavaScript:
`txtPassword.getElement().executeJs("document.getElementsByTagName('vaadin-password-field-button')" .setAttribute('attribute', 'value')");`

Any help on this approach or maybe different ideas welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aria-label` from the password field is a calculated value coming from a `i18n` property (a map, that as of now (v24) contains a `reveal` key).  It seems, that this property is not accessible via some more elegant API (also as of now (v24)), but you can set properties like this quite easily via the `Element`-API.

E.g.

```
new PasswordField().tap {
    getElement().setPropertyMap(
        'i18n',
        [reveal: "Another Aria Label"]
    )
}
```